# How to use only several fields of object for REST service

Tags: java, spring, rest, jackson

I'm creating RESTful WS with Spring. Now, for every WS I'm creating new classes for several object. And for the endpoint I'm using these classes as request data and Jackson automatically converts it but what if I want to use only few fields of that object for the another endpoint? I don't want to create another class for that.

For example, I have a model:

```
public class Salary {

    /*
     * Request Params
     */
    @JsonProperty("ID")
    private String documentId;

    @JsonProperty("DOCUMENTDATE")
    private Date createdDate;

    @JsonProperty("DOCUMENTNUMBER")
    private String documentNumber;

    @JsonProperty("PAYERACCOUNT")
    private String payer;

    @JsonProperty("RECEIVERACCOUNT")
    private String receiver;

    @JsonProperty("AMOUNT")
    private Double amount;

    @JsonProperty("CURRCODE")
    private String currency;

    @JsonProperty("GROUND")
    private String ground;

    /* Getters & Setters */
    // etc
}
```

And the endpoint:

```
@PostMapping("salaries")
public Response createSalary(@RequestBody Salary salary) {
    return salaryManager.createSalary(salary);
}

// There I want to use not the whole fields of Salary, but only documentDate and documentNumber
@PostMapping("salaries/transfer")
public Response transferSalary(@RequestBody Salary salary) {
    return salaryManager.transferSalary(salary);
}
```

So, in the above example in the second endpoint I want to accept as request only few params of Salary class.

Comment: may I ask what happens if you set the RequestBody(required=false) ?

Comment: @EiriniGraonidou actually nothing, the same behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the following json, and you don't want every property of the motor,

```
 { 
       "name": "kia",
       "motor": {
          "created_date": "2017-01-01",
          "size": "1L",
          "power": "44kw",
       },
       "model": "rio",
       "country": "south korea",
       "currency": "USD",
       "price": "14000"
 }
```

you could model the motor attribute in your DTO as String like:

```
public class Car {

   public String name;
   // define the attribute, that you want to save flat as a String.
   private String motor;

   //or define specific attributes of the motor, that you want to parse.
   private String motorPower;

   // use the map as input and parse only the attributes that you need.
   @JsonProperty("motor")
   public String parseMotorAttributes(Map<String,Object> motorInfo) {
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      sb.append("size: ")
        .append((String)motorInfo.get("size"));

      this.motor = sb.toString();

      //set the concrete attributes you defined
      this.motorPower = (String)motorInfo.get("power");
      return this.motor;
   }

   public String country;

   public String currency;

   public String price;

}
```

Comment: @catscoolzhyk I think that after you editing your question this answer is out of context. Would you agree?

Comment: yes, I agree =) Anyway for me it was useful information

Answer (score 0):

I don't know is this a proper solution, but what I do is just expect as usual the same object in request, and further I just validate desired fields and that is it.